# Getting 'NA' for not finding gender in gender package in R

Tags: r, missing-data

i want to know how I can get all the value that could not be processed with the gender package. Please have a look at the following code:

```r
library(gender)
test = tibble::tribble(
              ~Name1,
             "Peter",
             "Susan",
         "Nuernberg",
              "Test",
             "Heiko",
                "He"
         )
test$Name1 <- as.character(test$Name1) 
genderpred = gender(test$Name1, method = "ssa")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

As you can see, genderpred does not contain the not known gender. How can I get them into the matrix with 'NA'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Given `test` as a "matrix" (really a `tibble`) of names, you can simply use `dplyr::right_join()` as follows

```
library(gender)
library(dplyr)

# ...
# Your code to get the 'test' dataset of names.
# ...

# Consolidate any names (Name1, Name2, ...) into a single column.
consolidated <- data.frame(all_names = as.character(as.vector(as.matrix(test))))

# Get the gender predictions.
genderpred <- gender(consolidated$all_names, method = "ssa")

# Perform the join using the consolidated names.
genderpred <- genderpred %>%
  right_join(consolidated, by = c("name" = "all_names"))
```

to get your desired result for `genderpred`, like:

```
  name    proportion_male proportion_female gender year_min year_max
  <chr>             <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Peter            0.995             0.0053 male       1985     1985
2 Susan            0.0067            0.993  female     1985     1985
3 Nuernberg       NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
4 Test            NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
5 Heiko           NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
6 He              NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
```

By using a `right_join`, you include *all* the names from `test`: not just those with a matching `name` in `genderpred`. When such a name (like `"Nuernberg"`) has no match, it populates a new row that is "blank" (filled with `NA`s).

The `dplyr` documentation for `join`s can be found [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html).

## Update

Per the poster's [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67823446/getting-na-for-not-finding-gender-in-gender-package-in-r#comment119901598_67824485), I have extended the code (above) to handle multiple name columns in `test`.  As such, an initial `test` dataset like

```
test <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Name1,      ~Name2,       # ...  ~Name_n
  "Peter",     "Gary",       # ...     .
  "Susan",     "Mary",       # ...     .
  "Nuernberg", "Heisenberg", # ...     .
  "Test",      "And",        # ...     .
  "Heiko",     "So",         # ...     .
  "He",        "Forth"       # ...     .
)
```

will give a result for `genderpred` like

```
   name       proportion_male proportion_female gender year_min year_max
   <chr>                <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Gary                0.996             0.0035 male       1932     2012
 2 Mary                0.0038            0.996  female     1932     2012
 3 Peter               0.997             0.0032 male       1932     2012
 4 Susan               0.0023            0.998  female     1932     2012
 5 Nuernberg          NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
 6 Test               NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
 7 Heiko              NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
 8 He                 NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
 9 Heisenberg         NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
10 And                NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
11 So                 NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
12 Forth              NA                NA      NA           NA       NA
```

which can then be filtered (`dplyr::filter()`) and sorted (`dplyr::arrange()`) as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But how would I do this if I would have a matrix with multiple columns and not only one dimension like my example where all the names are stored under "name1"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd *need* a `test` matrix with more than one name column.  That said, **if you want a result of the same form** as my `genderpred` above, you can simply consolidate `test` into a single `name` column when performing the join.  I'll add an edit soon to that effect.

Comment: Hi @MaxH., I just updated the code to handle a `test` matrix with multiple name columns.